# Access 2007 VBA: Set Tabledef.Connect property to invalid path

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I've been asked to do some maintenance on an Access 2007 VBA database.

It has linked tables to another Access database in the same folder. It had hard-coded links to that database, so if the user copied the folder to a new folder, it tried to use the linked database in the original folder. They asked me to eliminate the danger of using the wrong linked database in that scenario.

I added code that runs when the database is opened, to make it reset the links to the database in it's own folder. If the linked database isn't there or was renamed, the user is prompted to browse to the correct database. So far so good.

But if the user cancels that dialog, I don't want to leave it connected to the wrong database. I want to set the linked tabledef's Connect property to the "correct" path even though the table is not there. Then the user will get an error that the linked table isn't there until they copy in the linked database -- rather than inadvertently use the wrong database.

When I use Resume Next to get past the error that is raised when I set the Connect property to a nonexistent database, the change doesn't stick, leaving it connected to the wrong database. So for now, I'm closing the database when that happens (after alerting the user that the linked database can't be found). That's safe in terms of not using the wrong database, but I don't think it's the ideal user experience.

So -- is it possible to set the Tabledef's Connect property to a nonexistent database?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: You could store the path to the linked database in a table and check that it is the same as the currentproject.path when the database is opened.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to set the Tabledef's Connect property to a nonexistent database?

I don't think so. I recommend you delete all of the linked tables first, and then if there's no database to connect to, show an error saying so.

In order to relink the tables you will then need to have a local table in your frontend file that holds a list of all tables to be linked. Then you'll need to loop through that list every time you need to relink the tables, assuming that the links have all been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update table links to render them invalid you need to

- create a temporary copy of the back-end database (or perhaps a temporary copy of a "skeleton" back-end database with empty tables),
- update the table links to point to the temporary database, and then
- delete the temporary database.

For example, if I run the following code

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub MakeBadLink()
    Const linkedTableName = "myLinkedTable"  ' test value
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Dim tempFolder As String, linkedDb As String, tempDb As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    linkedDb = Mid(cdb.TableDefs(linkedTableName).Connect, 11)  ' remove ";DATABASE=" prefix
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & "\"
    tempDb = tempFolder & fso.GetFileName(linkedDb)
    fso.CopyFile linkedDb, tempDb, True
    Set tbd = cdb.TableDefs(linkedTableName)
    tbd.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & tempDb
    tbd.RefreshLink
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    fso.DeleteFile tempDb
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

then any subsequent attempts to use [myLinkedTable] result in the error

> Could not find file `C:\Users\Gord\AppData\Local\Temp\myDb.accdb'.